# For any Subspace $A$ of a Path-Connected Space $X$, we have $H_0(X, A)=0$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-verification, homology-cohomology

I recently learnt about relative homologies and am wondering if the following is true:

> **Statement:** Let $X$ be a path-connected topological space and $A$ be a non-empty subspace of $X$. Then $H_0(X, A)=0$.

My argument is this: We need to show that the map $\bar \partial:C_1(X)/C_1(A)\to C_0(X)/C_0(A)$ is surjective.

So let $x+C_0(A)$ be an arbitrary member of $C_0(X)/C_0(A)$. Let $a\in A$ be arbitrary. Since $X$ is path-connected, there is a path $\gamma:I\to X$ such that $\gamma(1)=x$ and $\gamma(0)=a$.

Now $\bar \partial(\gamma+C_1(A))=\gamma(1)-\gamma(0)+C_0(A)=x-a+C_0(A)$. But since $a\in A$, we have $x-a+C_0(A)=x+C_0(A)$. Thus $x+C_0(A)$ is in the image of $\bar\partial$, meaning $\bar\partial$ is surjective.

Is the statement correct? If not, then can someone please point out an error in the argument? Thanks.

Comment: Looks fine to me. If you like, you can also prove this statement using the long exact sequence of homology groups.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Thank you. Using your approach, we just need to observe that the map $i_*:H_0(A)\to H_0(X)\cong \mathbb Z$ is surjective. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: @AmitaiYuval "Exactly". Nice. Thanks for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [$H_0(X,A) = 0 \iff A \cap X_i \neq \emptyset \forall $ path-components $X_i$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61967/h-0x-a-0-iff-a-cap-x-i-neq-emptyset-forall-path-components-x-i)

Comment: Of course it's not a perfect duplicate, the linked question is much more general. But I don't think it's necessary to have both questions on the site.

Comment: I think there is one missing step in the proof: An arbitrary member in $C_0(X)/C_0(A)$ is $\sum m_x \sigma_x$ for some $x \in X$. But the same argument follows. Please correct me if I am wrong.